# Python matplotlib how to change y-values of "histogram"

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to create a "histogram", except the y-axis is not supposed to be the frequency of data points within a bin. Instead, I wish to set my own y-axis values for each bin.

For example, let's say my `x` values are:`[1, 2.2, 1.4, 2, 3.3, 2.6, 3, 1.5, 3.9] and my y-values are [1, 2, 2.5, 1, 0.5, 3, 4, 3, 2]`

Treat this as a function: each of the `x` values corresponds to the `y`-values (i.e., the value in the 1st index of `x` array maps to the value in the 1st  index of `y` array, 2nd index to 2nd, etc.).

I wish to bin the `x` values and plot the sum of the `y` values corresponding to the x values of each bin.

For example, let's say I were to create 3 bins. The first bin would contain the `x` values `1, 1.4, 1.5,` and what gets plotted for this bin is the sum of the corresponding y values (so `1 + 2.5 + 3 = 6.5`).

How can I achieve this?

Edit: I guess a simpler question is: how do I create a bar graph with numerical numbers as the x-axis and with continuous bars (i.e. no gap between bars)

Comment: I add code to plot bars, is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I used your example data, and here is the code

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2.2, 1.4, 2, 3.3, 2.6, 3, 1.5, 3.9])
# sort x and y
ind = np.argsort(x)
x1 = x[ind]
y = np.array([1, 2, 2.5, 1, 0.5, 3, 4, 3, 2])
y1 = y[ind]

# count bins
y2, t = np.histogram(x1, bins=3)
ind1 = y2.cumsum()
ind2 = np.array([0]+[e for e in ind1[0:-1]])

# sum based on counts
y_final = [y1[i:j].sum() for (i, j) in zip(ind2, ind1)]

# plot bar, specify the width
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
ax.bar(t[0:3], y_final, width=np.diff(t)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be describing the `weights=` argument of [`plt.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2.2, 1.4, 2, 3.3, 2.6, 3, 1.5, 3.9]
y = [1, 2, 2.5, 1, 0.5, 3, 4, 3, 2]
plt.hist(x, weights=y, bins=3)
```

At the left the default histogram and at the center with `histtype='step'` which more resembles how a function would be plotted. The subplot at the right adds a [`stem`plot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stem.html) showing the x and corresponding y values.

[image: example plot]

Comment: this is way much better than my answer:) thanks!, I also learned a lot.